# How to add langdetect's language probability vector to a Keras Sequential Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I'm currently studying the singing language identification problem (and the basics of machine learning). I found lots of works about this on the internet, but some of them don't provide any code (or even pseudocode) and that's why I'm trying to reproduce them using their machine learning model description.

A good example is `LISTEN, READ, AND IDENTIFY: MULTIMODAL SINGING LANGUAGE IDENTIFICATION OF MUSIC` written by Keunwoo Choi and Yuxuan Wang.

To sum up, they are concatenating two layers: audio layer (in form of spectrogram), text layer (language probability vector on metadata using langdetect, 56-dimensional vector).

`The text branch is a 3-layer MLP where each layer consists of a 128-unit fully-connected layer, a batch normalization layer, and a ReLU activation [22].`

For text model I got something like this:

```
text_model = Sequential()
text_model.add(Input((56,), name='input'))
text_model.add(BatchNormalization())
text_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
```

`langdetect.detect_langs(metadata)` returns `[de:0.8571399874707945, en:0.14285867860989504]`.

I m not sure I've described my model correctly and I cannot understand how to put it properly (langdetect probability vector) into keras model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to transform the `langdetect` output into vector of a constant length. There are 55 languages in the library, therefore we need to create vector of length 55, where i-th element represents the probability of text coming from the i-th language. You could do this like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import langdetect

langdetect.detector_factory.init_factory()
LANGUAGES_LIST = langdetect.detector_factory._factory.langlist

def get_probabilities_vector(text):
    
    predictions = langdetect.detect_langs(text)
    output = np.zeros(len(LANGUAGES_LIST))
    
    for p in predictions:
        output[LANGUAGES_LIST.index(p.lang)] = p.prob
        
    return tf.constant(output)
```

Then you need to create a model with multiple inputs. This can be done using [functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional), e.g. like this (change your inputs according to your use case):

```py
def create_model():
    
    audio_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256,))
    langdetect_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(55,))
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([audio_input, langdetect_input])
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(55)(x)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(
        inputs={
            'audio': audio_input,
            'text': langdetect_input
        },
        outputs=output)
        
    return model
```

Testing the model on some input:

```py
model = create_model()

audio_input = tf.constant(np.random.rand(256))
langdetect_input = get_probabilities_vector('This is just a test input')

model({
    'audio': tf.expand_dims(audio_input, 0),
    'text': tf.expand_dims(langdetect_input, 0)
})

>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 55), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.23361185,  0.19011918, -0.45230836, -0.0602392 , -0.20067683,
         0.9698535 , -1.0724173 ,  0.08978442,  0.052798  , -0.16554174,
         0.9238764 ,  1.0331644 ,  0.4508734 , -0.2450786 , -1.0605856 ,
         0.3239496 , -1.0073977 , -0.2129285 , -0.6817296 ,  0.05288622,
         0.9089616 , -0.11521344,  0.25696573, -0.07688305, -0.36123943,
        -0.0317415 , -0.18303779,  0.13786468,  0.88620317,  0.11393422,
        -0.5215691 , -0.28585738,  0.54988045, -0.02300271, -0.4347821 ,
        -0.57744324,  0.14031887,  0.8255624 , -0.13157232, -1.1060234 ,
        -0.24097277,  0.12950295,  0.4586677 ,  0.37702668,  0.7558856 ,
        -0.05933011,  0.53903174,  0.27433476, -0.18464057,  1.0673125 ,
        -0.05723387, -0.03429477,  0.4431308 , -0.14510366, -0.28087378]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

I am expanding the dimensions of the inputs using [expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) function so that the inputs have shapes `(1, 256)` and `(1, 55)` (which is similar to inputs `(batch_size, 256)` and `(batch_size, 55)` that the model expects during training).

This is just a draft, but this is roughly how your problem could be solved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! 

I've just tried out your code and changed my model: https://pastebin.com/RSn2Zs8T
Dataset generation and fitting: https://pastebin.com/t1sKzsYZ

But now I'm getting such exception:

`Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for '{{node model/concatenate/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](IteratorGetNext, IteratorGetNext:1, model/concatenate/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,?,?,1], [?,55], [].`

Comment: I am on a mobile right now so I can't test your code, but the problem seems to be this: you declare `audio_input` as `Input` layer, but then re-declare its value. You should do something like: `audio_x = melspectrogram_layer(audio_input)` and then continue inputting and re-declaring the `audio_x` object until you input it into the concatenate layer. If the problem persists, there is something wrong with handling the audio input. At the end of handling audio input, the branch should have output of dimension 2 (same as text input), the error says that it currently has dimension 4.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works. Yes, the problem was that I was redeclaring the input